# file writing not working as expected

Tags: python, file-writing

I have a python code where it will take the first column of a sample.csv file and copy it to temp1.csv file. Now I would like to compare this csv file with another serialNumber.txt file for any common rows. If any common rows found, It should write to a result file. My temp1.csv is being created properly but the problem is the result file which is being created is empty.

script.py

```
import csv
f = open("sample.csv", "r")
reader = csv.reader(f)

data = open("temp1.csv", "wb")
w = csv.writer(data)
for row in reader:
    my_row = []
    my_row.append(row[0])
    w.writerow(my_row)
data.close()

with open('temp1.csv', 'r') as file1:
    with open('serialNumber.txt', 'r') as file2:
        same = set(file1).intersection(file2)
        print same

with open('result.csv', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in same:
        file_out.write(line)
        print line
```

sample.csv

```
M11435TDS144,STB#1,Router#1 
M11543TH4292,STB#2,Router#1 
M11509TD9937,STB#3,Router#1
M11543TH4258,STB#4,Router#1
```

serialNumber.txt

```
G1A114042400571
M11543TH4258
M11251TH1230
M11435TDS144
M11543TH4292
M11509TD9937
```

Comment: file1 and file2 as you have them are file objects thus they cannot be the same.  You need to read in each line into some object (a set works) and then take the intersection of the two sets.

Comment: When reading `temp1.csv` back in, do you need to use a `csv.reader`, instead of reading it as a plain file?

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('temp1.csv', 'r') as file1:
    list1 = file1.readlines()

set1 = set(list1)

with open('temp2.csv', 'r') as file2:
    list2 = file2.readlines()

set2 = set(list2)
```

now you can process the contents as sets

I want to note that your original code does not insert line breaks after each line so I am not sure if they would be present.  If not you need to add those, otherwise you will have a mess

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this instead

```
same = set(list(file1)).intersection(list(file2))
```